# Selecting from Multiple tables in same Query using PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select

Kindly pardon me if i looks silly , I am newbie in PhP MySQL

Totally there are three tables

> Student,Class,Parent

I am working on parent user now . As a parent i want to view some things as below

> 1. My Students studying
> 2. Their class

Student Table :

```
s_id   s_name    parent_id   s_class_id   

1       name1     40           20
```

Class Table :

```
c_id   c_name   

20      Ten
```

Parent Table :

```
p_id    p_name

40      Parent1
```

My 1st task as mentioned above "1. My Students studying " i done successfully with the following query

```
"SELECT * FROM student where parent_id='$update_id' "
```

then by displaying

```
$row['s_name']
```

For all who thinks where the `$update id` comes from , I already done it few codes above as follows

```
$update_id = $login_type['p_id'];
```

Where `$login_type` i am taking from session

Now i want to do my second task which is "2. Their class"

I don't want it to do as separate select query which i can do now, i want it to be in the same select above done . as i am just learning from scratch i am stuck over here . Kindly help me please mates.

I tried to explain the max as i can , if you still has any clarifications , kindly ask me .

Comment: `SELECT s.*,c.c_name FROM student s INNER JOIN Class c ON(s.s_class_id = c.cid)  where s.parent_id='$update_id'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `join` to get results from multiple tables.
Your query should look similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM student 
    JOIN class 
    ON class.c_id = student.s_class_id
    WHERE parent_id='$update_id'
```

You can read more about mysql `join` here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Really? is this valid MySQL syntax?

Comment: @DanielDudas Thanks, This worked like a charm mate . By the way i am going through the `join` documentation you referred mate .

Comment: @sagi Is this not a valid MySQL syntax mate ? kindly help me please. I am asking because i am getting output perfectly with this syntax . But anyhow if you feel as this is not a valid syntax kindly update me with the fix in the syntax as i will learn properly. My intention is not the output but the proper syntax mate.

Comment: @RajaGopal He updated his question since, it wasn't formatted like this! You can press on the `edited -x- mins ago` to see edit history.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM student
INNER JOIN class ON class.c_id = student.s_class_id 
WHERE parent_id = '$update_id'
```

You can use `mysql` `join` query like this and can get the student's class name in

```
$row['c_name']
```

Answer (score 1):

In this single SELECT you can obtain all data from tables 'student' and 'class' related to the students with parent_id='$update_id' using JOIN.

```
SELECT * FROM student 
LEFT JOIN class ON s_class_id=c_id
WHERE parent_id='$update_id'
```

To access the data from, use same method you already use:

```
echo $row['s_name'];
echo $row['c_name'];
// ..and so on for other fields.
```

[Edited: added LEFT to join, so that you will get data from ALL students, including those not having any class assigned. With INNER JOIN (or JOIN 'only') you will miss rows from students with no class]